# Algorithmic issue

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to find a `O (n)` algorithm for this problem but unable to do so even after spending 3 - 4 hours. The brute force method times out `(O (n^2))`. I am confused as to how to do it ? Does the solution requires dynamic programming solution ?

http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1794

In short the problem is this:

There are some students sitting in circle and each one of them has its own choice as to when he wants to be asked a question from a teacher. The teacher will ask the questions in clockwise order only. For example:

```
5

3 3 1 5 5
```

This means that there are 5 students and :

```
1st student wants to go third
2nd student wants to go third
3rd student wants to go first
4th student wants to go fifth
5th student wants to go fifth.
```

The question is as to where should teacher start asking questions so that maximum number of students will get the turn as they want. For this particular example, the answer is 5 because

```
3 3 1 5 5

2 3 4 5 1
```

You can see that by starting at fifth student as 1st, 2 students (3 and 5) are getting the choices as they wanted. For this example the answer is 12th student :

```
12

5 1 2 3 6 3 8 4 10 3 12 7
```

because

```
5 1 2 3 6 3 8 4 10   3 12 7

2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 1
```

four students get their choices fulfilled.

Comment: Please include the question, or better a summary of it in your question text.

Comment: Each student gets their wish for *exactly* one possible starting position, "close" is worth nothing. So each student's requested speaking position can be re-interpreted as a vote for who they want to speak first. You're asked to find the starter with most votes. A much harder problem would be to ask how the students should have arranged themselves in the circle in the first place, but by the time this problem starts, that's fixed :-)

Comment: The original description says that n ≤ 10⁵. This puts any solution in O(n²) also in O(10⁵⋅n) and thereby in O(n).

Comment: @Oswal Whaaaa? By the same deduction, we could say the solution is in O(1). Not true at all. Just because the question constrains N, doesn't make the runtime not grow as N grows. A deduction like you make would only hold if N was a *constant* equal to 100,000. Even then, that's not a very practical deduction.

Comment: @Steve Your "much harder" problem is also trivial. You can easily arrange the students such that for each position that is wanted by a student, one student gets that position.

Comment: @Chris: if they know where the teacher is going to start numbering them, sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually a rather simple problem. If student k wants to be the jth to present, then she will be satisfied iff the (k - j + 1)th (modulo n) is the first to present. This should lead you to a a simple O(n) algorithm.

Comment: But what of competing desires from other students? I think you've simplified this too much.

Comment: @San Jacinto No, I haven't. Let me tell you the simple O(n) algorithm. Iterate once through the list accumulating how many students are satisfied for each starting position `for (i=1:n) sat[i - want[i] + 1]++` then find the index of the maximum value in sat.